# Use SFML libraries with bazel

Tags: c++, sfml, bazel

How can I use SFML libraries which already installed in the system via apt-get in Bazel?
How to create a cc_library rule for that?

I want to avoid the way through http_archive rule.

Comment: Comment moved to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to solve the problem with simple linker commands like this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lsfml-graphics",
        "-lsfml-window",
        "-lsfml-system",
    ]
)
```